Scroll with headers - QTableView / QTableWidget
Vertical and horizontal headers are frozen by default when using the scrollbars if the table is not visible. I would like the scroll to apply to the headers as well, so when scrolling, they are not visible at all time.
Here is the example:
import string
import random
from typing import Optional

from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QTableWidget, QWidget, QAbstractItemView, QHeaderView, QTableWidgetItem, QHBoxLayout, \
    QApplication


class DataTable(QTableWidget):

    # region Constructor

    def __init__(self, parent: Optional[QWidget] = None):
        super(DataTable, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectItems)
        self.setHorizontalScrollMode(QAbstractItemView.ScrollPerPixel)

        self.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.horizontalHeader().setTextElideMode(Qt.ElideMiddle)

        for j in range(20):
            if self.columnCount() <= j:
                self.insertColumn(j)
            for i in range(20):
                if self.rowCount() <= i:
                    self.insertRow(i)
                self.setItem(i, j, QTableWidgetItem('Hello'))

        word = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(6))
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels([str(word) for i in range(self.columnCount())])
        self.setVerticalHeaderLabels([str(word) for i in range(self.rowCount())])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication()

    widget = QWidget()
    widget.resize(400, 600)
    layout = QHBoxLayout(widget)
    layout.addWidget(DataTable())
    widget.show()

    app.exec()

This is how it looks (see scrollbar is at the right):

How i'd like to look (basically the horizontal and vertical headers should move with the scroll):


To anyone interested, I the code below works. So I basically wrapped the QTableWidget in a QScrollArea, disabled the scrollbars from the QTableWidget and updated the minimum size.
import string
import random
from typing import Optional

from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QSize
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QTableWidget, QWidget, QAbstractItemView, QHeaderView, QTableWidgetItem, QHBoxLayout, \
    QApplication, QScrollArea


class DataTable(QScrollArea):

    # region Constructor

    def __init__(self, parent: Optional[QWidget] = None):
        super(DataTable, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWidget(DataTableWidget(self))
        self.setWidgetResizable(True)


class DataTableWidget(QTableWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent: Optional[QWidget] = None):
        super(DataTableWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectItems)
        self.setHorizontalScrollMode(QAbstractItemView.ScrollPerPixel)

        self.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.horizontalHeader().setTextElideMode(Qt.ElideMiddle)

        self.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QAbstractItemView.AdjustToContents)

        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        for j in range(20):
            if self.columnCount() <= j:
                self.insertColumn(j)
            for i in range(20):
                if self.rowCount() <= i:
                    self.insertRow(i)
                self.setItem(i, j, QTableWidgetItem('Hello'))

        word = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(6))
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels([str(word) for i in range(self.columnCount())])
        self.setVerticalHeaderLabels([str(word) for i in range(self.rowCount())])

        self.setMinimumSize(self.get_table_widget_size())

    def get_table_widget_size(self):
        w = self.verticalHeader().width() + 4  # +4 seems to be needed
        for i in range(self.columnCount()):
            w += self.columnWidth(i)  # seems to include gridline (on my machine)
        h = self.horizontalHeader().height() + 4
        for i in range(self.rowCount()):
            h += self.rowHeight(i)
        return QSize(w, h)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication()

    widget = QWidget()
    widget.resize(400, 600)
    layout = QHBoxLayout(widget)
    layout.addWidget(DataTable())
    widget.show()

    app.exec()


The proposed solution from the OP works perfectly fine, it is actually based on the concept of reparenting, which creates some relatively important issues; for instance:

accessing object members is not immediate (even though creating a persistent attribute to the actual table widget would obviously make that more "transparent");
there are actually two scroll areas (with their related borders);
the size hint of the table will force its size to its minimum requirements, preventing proper expansion;
due to the reason above, the headers may not expand as they might want to;
there is no immediate way to extend the possible size hint requirements of the table to the parent scroll area;
wheel events may become more complex to handle;

QTableView (on which QTableWidget is based) doesn't make it easy to get what requested, but that does not mean it is impossible to achieve.
We only need to patiently go through all the implementation, including the inheritance tree. Consider the following structure:

QTableWidget: it has its own methods for item management;

QTableView: implements two QHeaderViews, overrides QAbstractItemView::updateGeometries() and QAbstractItemView::scrollTo();

QAbstractItemView

QAbstractScrollArea

QFrame

QWidget

QObject













updateGeometries() is called frequently, usually whenever a Resize event is called on the widget or its viewport (including geometry changes that may affect that, such size hint changes in its headers or its editors).
scrollTo() has to be overridden in order to consider scrolling offset of translated headers.
The scroll bars also affect the appearance of the view and all its contents, including its headers' geometries and offsets, which, in turn, are used to know the geometry of each item, both for displaying and user interaction.
In order to achieve the wanted result, we need to do the following updates:

the view geometries, ensuring that the viewport margins are consistent with the header geometries;
the header geometries based on the scroll values;
the header offsets, that tell the view how much its items have been "scrolled";
possibly check related widgets (such as the "corner button");
fix the scrollTo() function in order to consider the header offsets;

The above is done by properly overriding scrollContentsBy() and updateGeometries(), and also by connecting the vertical and horizontal scroll bars to a function that properly updates the offset of each header.
The following code can be used as a mixin for both QTableView and QTableWidget:
class ScrollHeaderTableHelper(object):
    _recursionGuard = False
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.horizontalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(self._fixScrollOffset)
        self.verticalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(self._fixScrollOffset)

    def cornerButton(self):
        try:
            return self._cornerButton
        except:
            for b in self.findChildren(QAbstractButton):
                if b.metaObject().className() == 'QTableCornerButton':
                    def destroy():
                        del self._cornerButton
                    self._cornerButton = b
                    b.destroyed.connect(destroy)
                    return b

    def updateGeometries(self):
        if self._recursionGuard:
            # only update common view widgets, not QTableView specific ones
            QAbstractItemView.updateGeometries(self)
            return
        super().updateGeometries()

    def scrollContentsBy(self, dx, dy):
        hHeader = self.horizontalHeader()
        vHeader = self.verticalHeader()
        vBar = self.verticalScrollBar()
        hBar = self.horizontalScrollBar()

        super().scrollContentsBy(dx, dy)

        # update header offsets based on the scroll mode or amount: if the 
        # mode is ScrollPerItem, let the view manage the visibility of the 
        # headers also based on _fixScrollOffset; alternatively, update the 
        # offset based on the header width as long as it is not visible, 
        # otherwise just set it to "0" so that it's properly updated based 
        # on the related scroll bar.

        if self.horizontalScrollMode() == self.ScrollMode.ScrollPerPixel:
            if hBar.value() <= vHeader.width():
                hHeader.setOffset(0)
            else:
                hHeader.setOffset(hBar.value() - vHeader.width())

        if self.verticalScrollMode() == self.ScrollMode.ScrollPerPixel:
            if vBar.value() <= hHeader.height():
                vHeader.setOffset(0)
            else:
                vHeader.setOffset(vBar.value() - hHeader.height())

    def scrollTo(self, index, hint=QAbstractItemView.ScrollHint.EnsureVisible):
        hBar = self.horizontalScrollBar()
        vBar = self.verticalScrollBar()
        oldX = hBar.value()
        oldY = vBar.value()

        super().scrollTo(index, hint)

        if self.horizontalScrollMode() == self.ScrollMode.ScrollPerPixel:
            newX = hBar.value()
            if newX and newX != oldX:
                hBar.setValue(newX + self.verticalHeader().width())
        if self.verticalScrollMode() == self.ScrollMode.ScrollPerPixel:
            newY = vBar.value()
            if newY and newY != oldY:
                vBar.setValue(newY + self.horizontalHeader().height())

    def _fixScrollOffset(self):
        self._recursionGuard = True

        hHeader = self.horizontalHeader()
        vHeader = self.verticalHeader()
        hBar = self.horizontalScrollBar()
        vBar = self.verticalScrollBar()

        if self.verticalScrollMode() == self.ScrollMode.ScrollPerItem:
            # show the horizontal header only if the first row is visible
            if vBar.value():
                y = -hHeader.height()
            else:
                y = 0
        elif vBar.value() >= hHeader.height():
            # scrolling is beyond the first row, hide the horizontal header
            y = -hHeader.height()
        else:
            # partially hide the horizontal header based on the scroll value
            y = -vBar.value()

        # the following is similar to the above, but for the vertical header
        if self.horizontalScrollMode() == self.ScrollMode.ScrollPerItem:
            if hBar.value():
                x = -vHeader.width()
            else:
                x = 0
        elif hBar.value() >= vHeader.width():
            x = -vHeader.width()
        else:
            x = -hBar.value()

        height = hHeader.height() + y
        width = vHeader.width() + x

        self.setViewportMargins(width, height, 0, 0)
        vg = self.viewport().geometry()
        left = vg.x() - width
        top = vg.y() - height

        vHeader.setGeometry(
            x + left, y + hHeader.height() + top, 
            vHeader.width(), vg.height()
        )
        hHeader.setGeometry(
            x + vHeader.width() + left, 
            y + top, vg.width(), hHeader.height()
        )

        try:
            self.cornerButton().move(x, y)
        except AttributeError:
            pass

        self._recursionGuard = False

A basic example using the above:
class DataTable(ScrollHeaderTableHelper, QTableWidget): pass

...

layout.addWidget(DataTable())

Note that the above is a relatively crude implementation that doesn't consider some extended aspects: it should work on very basic situations, but it lacks support for more accurate implementation (most importantly, systems or locales based on right-to-left writing layouts). Implementing those should be fairly easy, though.
